# Is my definition of division by zero problematic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition

I am a complete amateur, but I've attempted to define division by zero. This it's usually classified as undefined. After all, if 1/0 = b, where b is some non-zero number, then b times 0 would have to equal 1, and there exists no real number that, when multiplied by zero, equals 1.
Therefore, it was evident that my definition would necessitate the creation of a new kind of number. This number, which I call Z, is defined as Z=1/0.  Z is thus the reciprocal of 0.
Playing with this new number for awhile less me to discover that 2/0=2Z, and so on where n/0=nZ.  This leads to a whole set of numbers, Z numbers, similar to imaginary numbers. After all, imaginary numbers were created to define something that was formerly undefined, namely, a number whose square was -1.  This leads to the whole set of imaginary / complex numbers.
Already I've discovered interesting facts about this number Z, such as the square of Z is equal to Z, since 1/0 times 1/0 equals 1/0.
My question is, is there some way in which my new set of numbers to define division by zero falls apart under closer scrutiny? I have yet to discover one, but I'm very new to mathematical exploration. 
I apologize for not being familiar with the Math font used to write equations.

Comment: Pretending to play the game, $-1/0=(-1)/0=Z$ but also $-1/0=-(1/0)= -Z$ so $Z=-Z \iff 2Z = 0 \iff Z=0$. But of course $Z=0$ doesn't work since $1 \ne 0 \cdot 0$.

Comment: I think you quickly run into problems with your definition if you want any of the standard rules of arithmetic to apply. For example, if $Z^2 = Z$ as you say, then we should also have $Z^2 \times 0^2 = Z \times 0^2 = (Z \times 0) \times 0 = 1 \times 0 = 0$, but on the other hand $Z^2 \times 0^2 = (Z \times 0)^2 = 1^2 = 1$.

Comment: This doesn't seem any different from the symbol $\infty$ any entails the same difficulties.  What is $Z-Z?$ or $Z/Z?$

Comment: @dxiv I'm not sure how you conclude, just from what's given in the post, that $(-1)/0$ should be equal to $Z$ in your first equation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to follow. You stated that -1/0 = (-1)/0 = Z, but by my property n/0 = nZ stated above, then when n = -1, shouldn't (-1)/0 = -1Z = -Z?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo Since $0=-0$ and pretending basic algebra stands $\,(-1)/0=1/(-0)=1/0=Z\,$.

Comment: Gregory, thanks, good point. However, I'm wondering if perhaps order of operations would negate your first answer since the zeros should be squared before being multiplied by Z?

Comment: You would lose associativity since $2 = 0\times(2\times Z) \ne (0\times 2)\times Z = 1$.

Comment: Good points all, thanks for helping. We could probably continue to go back and forth since a lot of the problems raised seem to be definition-based rather than arithmetic-based, but I won't belabor the discussion since this is a q and a rather than a discussion forum. Thanks for the input!

Comment: If you multiply $\frac{1}{0}$, your $z$, by $1$ in the form of $\frac{x}{x}$ (for some non-zero $x$), it would seem that you should get $$z = z \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{0}\cdot\frac{x}{x} = \frac{1\cdot x}{0\cdot x} = \frac{x}{0} = x \cdot z$$ That is, $z = xz$ for all non-zero $x$. That property is usually reserved for zero itself ... or "infinity". There's a bit of literature on the arithmetic of infinite numbers, so do some searching. For a semi-casual view, see "Infinity and the Mind" by Rudy Rucker; the text is available [on the author's website](http://www.rudyrucker.com/infinityandthemind/).

Comment: Why are you trying to divide by zero ?

Comment: @Rene, just attempting to tackle something for the fun of it. Since division by zero was undefined, I thought I'd try to define it and see where it led me. In other words, just playing!

Comment: But there are rules, and the rules imply division by 0 is impossible, so if you want to do it you have to throw out some of the rules, which rules do you want to keep and which to dispose of ?

Comment: Well, my understanding was that division by zero is not impossible, simply undefined. I was attempting to define it in a way that did not create problems. And the majority of so-called rules simply came to be by definition, not by absolute truth, so who's to say the rules are correct anyway? By the rules, finding the square root of -1 was impossible until i was defined.

Comment: That being said, my definition has conflicted with a lot of arithmetic properties, so you have a valid point. I was just playing around and thought I'd give it a whirl.

Comment: @KevinH There are good reasons to not define the definition by zero. This was not just laziness of the mathematicians.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Some people on this site insist that in the complex numbers together with the "infinity-point" a division by zero would make sense. Is this actually true ?

Comment: @Peter I understand it wasn't laziness. I did not mean to spark debate on this site. Mathematics isn't about rules, it's about creativity, problem-solving, and discovery. I attempted to tackle something new in a unique way, and asked for input, and several folks pointed out problems with my definition, which I now realize. However, it was not somehow "illegal" for me to attempt to define it. One can define their starting "rules" and invent their own entire branch of math if they so choose by experimenting with those starting rules. Most math "rules" are the by-product of someone's definition.

Comment: @Peter Nope, it isnt.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your definition of Z, we have $1/Z= 1/(1/0) =0$

Now we get $$2/Z = 2(0)=0 =1/Z$$ Multiply by $Z$ and we get $1=2$

Similarly you can prove $m=n$ for any two integers which we do not approve of.